# Spring MVC ajax re-rerendering user interface duplication

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsf, spring-mvc

First of all I am mainly with a `JSF` background.

I have started recently studying `Spring MVC`. One thing that is bothering me is the ajax re-rendering when using `Spring MVC` and `JQuery`.

Let's imagine that I have defined a complex form in my `people.jsp` view:

```
<c:forEach var="person" items="${people}">
   <table>
       <tr class="trPersonClass">...</tr>
       <tr>...</tr>
   </table>
</c:forEach>
```

And I have a `refresh` button below. When the refresh button is clicked I want with `ajax` the `people` to rerender.

```
function refreshButtonClicked() {
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "ajax/loadPeople.do"
    }).done(function( msg ) {   
        //WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE???            
    } 
});
```

So what I should do there? I have already defined how the people rendering should like with the `c:forEach` tag in my `jsp`. I don't want to repeat it again. I don't want to duplicate user interface code at both places - in the `JQuery` done callback and with `JSP` tags in my views. This is error prone in my opinion.

Please explain me kindly what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Spring MVC is very flexible. You can have backend handlers that return HTML generated by a view engine, you can have a handlers that returns JSON/XML/ProtocolBuffers/etc. and use client side rendering engines like Mustache etc. to display the page in the browser, or you can combine the two in the same application.

If you want to generate HTML on the server, Spring MVC allows you to use different template engines to do that. You can use JSP, Freemarker, Velocity etc. In order to do that, it uses a ViewResolver abstraction, and in your code you only have to deal with the ModelAndView API.

More details on ViewResolver can be found here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html

Based on your question it sounds like you have a backend that use JSP to create the html server side. In order to update only the table and not reload the entire page when a user clicks a refresh button, you could for example have a handler that returns only the html table like so:

```
@RequestMapping("/table")
public ModelAndView renderTable() {
   List<People> people = peopleService.findAllPeople();
   return new ModelAndView("/people", "people", people);
}
```

I'm also assuming you have another handler that returns the main page where the table is embedded via ajax.

```
<body>
    ...
    /* Content of div will be populated via ajax*/
    <div id="myTableContainer" />
    ...
</body>
```

The javaScript for this would be something like:

```
$(function() {

  var myTableContainer = $("#myTableContainer");

  var renderTable = function(container) { 
    $.get("/table", function(data) {
      container.empty().html(data);
    }
  };

  /* This is called on document ready */
  renderTable(myTableContainer);

  /* Use the same renderTable function when the refresh button is clicked */
  $("#refreshButton").click(function() {
      renderTable(myTableContainer);
  });
}
```

Comment: I think `container.empty().html(data);` won't work because you haven't returned the people as `JSON`. This is essentially what I am asking. I have to duplicate user interface code in the `renderTable` function - "<tr>" tags and so on. I have already defined it in my `jsp`. Why should I enter it again in the `renderTable` function?

Comment: The SpringMVC backend returns html, so `container.empty().html(data)` just embeds the html table that's returned by the backend into the page.

Comment: You are not duplicating any view logic. The JSP is responsible for creating the html, and it's done on the server. The JavaScript is responsible for updating a subset of you page (the table), it does so by calling the server side via ajax, take the returned html and replace the previously rendered table. Had the backend returned JSON, then you would need some way of creating the html in the client, but in this case html is only created on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, I see 2 options:

1. Always load the table using ajax, even on the first rendering (table creation code only in your javascript function)
2. Modify ajax/loadPeople.do to return an already rendered table instead of a Json list. You could then factor the people table rendering code in a JSP Tag file or use some templating library (tiles, etc.) to reuse that JSP fragment.