# How to use spring:eval expression inside $.each jQuery

Tags: spring, jquery, spring-mvc

After a ajax call the response received is a JSON String. I am able to list the data but was wondering if is it feasible to use spring:eval inside jQuery $.each? If someone has an example I would really appreciate. The line in question ends with "??"

Response received is JSON:

```
{"listOfData":[{"id":"XX","someValue":"James Bond"}]}
```

The rest of the code:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON_String)
$.each(obj.listOfData, function (index, data) {   
   "<tr>" +
       "<td style=\"padding: 3px;\">" +
           (index + 1) +
       "</td>" +
       "<td style=\"padding: 3px;\">" +                
           <spring:eval expression="data.someValue" /> ??
       "</td>" + 
    "</tr>" +
}
```

Comment: java_dude -- I am removing your answer from the question. If you found an answer please post it as an **answer** to the question, not as an update to your question.

Comment: Did not think of that. But that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are here then may be you are not on the right track. Try this solution. Works like a charm ... [`Solution 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816080/how-to-render-a-view-using-ajax-in-spring-mvc) and similar solution [`Solution 2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871598/spring-mvc-ajax-re-rerendering-user-interface-duplication).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where this code is,

```
<td style=\"padding: 3px;\"><spring:eval expression=\"data.someValue\" /></td>
```

might work. If it doesn't, you could do the "eval" part server side and return *ready-to-use* datas from your JSON code.

Comment: Nope.. That did not help but found a great solution. Edited my question with solution. Appreciate your response.